# Render the view differently depending on the published domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, view, razor, rendering, subdomain

Mypage.cshtml have a page and have a domain "xxx.com" and a subdomain "test.xxx.com" that when I publish my site in the subdomain "test.xxx.com" the title of the page shows something different. It would be something like:

```
@if (--Request.IsSubDomain("test")--)
{ 
    <h1>Test page: Product</h1>
}
else
{ 
    <h1>Product</h1>
}
```

Comment: Surprisingly similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6551954/how-to-find-the-source-of-a-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not want to have this login in your views. I personally would move this into a custom attribute or include the logic directly in your controllers.

By the way, what is the question?

**Edit:**

You could use `Request.Url.Authority` to determine the domain.

Comment: How do I know if the request was made by the main domain or subdomain in this case test.xxx.com?

Answer (score 0):

I don't normally recommend using `ViewBag`, but if you *only* want to use this to render a title, subclass your controllers from a parent controller say, `GeneralController` and set a `ViewBag.Title` property there based on domain.

One alternative to this is subclassing any view models from a base view model including similar logic.

```
public class GeneralController
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        if(HttpContext != null)
            ViewBag.Title = GetRequestPath();        
    }

    private string GetRequestTitle()
    {
        if(HttpContext.Request.Path.Contains("test.xxx"))
            return "Test site";
    }
}
```

Then, any controller and subsequently rendered views will be able to use this ViewBag.Title property. In fact, out of the box, MVC3 includes `_Layout.cshtml` as its default layout (or Master Page) that already contains the following line in the head:

```
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
```